# Version Tree in Clear Case Explorer is not working

Tags: clearcase, version-tree

I am using 8.0.1.6 version of Rational Clear Case Explorer.

Version Tree is not popping up while checking using the Tools -> Version Tree option in clear case explorer.

Comment: Sorry, but all I can do is ask questions here:
1) Did it JUST start happening?
2) Does it also happen when you run "cleartool lsvtree -gra {element name}" on the command line?
3) Is this happening to all users, some users, or only specific users?
4) Is the issue limited to one or multiple users?
5) Does the problem follow the users?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but all I can do is ask questions here:

1. Did it JUST start happening?
2. Does it also happen when you run "cleartool lsvtree -gra {element name}" on the command line?
3. Is this happening to all users, some users, or only specific users?
4. Is the issue limited to one or multiple users?
5. Does the problem follow the users?

You may want to delete the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\clearvtree key as a quick test. That is where user-specific settings for the vtree browser reside, and that may clear the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, see [technote swg21238290](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21238290): in addition of the registry cleartree key, you have other workarounds mentioned there.

But if you are not on Windows, or if you don't see any error message (meaning the clearvtree simply hang and refuse to be displayed), look for any log: Windows log event, and of course ClearCase logs using [`cleartool getlog`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm). You might find a clue there.